# How to copy the asset folder into the installation directory in wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In wix we can add necessory file into the wix file what and all we need it in our application.
we can copy single file in debug folder using

```
<Component Id="WpfApplication6.exe.config" Guid="281a18eb-e788-4067-b602-38f50445d65b">
          <File Id="WpfApplication6.exe.config" Name="WpfApplication6.exe.config" Source="$(var.WpfApplication6_TargetDir)WpfApplication6.exe.config" />
        </Component>
```

If i have a assets folder in my debug folder, if i want to copy the folder it self, what should i do?

i dont expect to copy file by file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the [HarvestDirectory Target](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestdirectory.html)

You'll just need to define a small item group in your wixproj like the example from the link

```
<ItemGroup>
  <HarvestDirectory Include="..\TestProject\Data">
    <DirectoryRefId>DataDir</DirectoryRefId>
    ... other properties ....
  </HarvestDirectory>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then when you build heat will automatically harvest your assets folder and include it in the install. You may need to use the $(Configuration) MSBuild property in your path to the directory to harvest since it is weird to put all your assets in a debug folder IMO.